# x-editable textarea, html values disappear on edit

Tags: javascript, x-editable

when using x-editable with a textarea that has html tags, they disappear when I click edit. If I add them again, they remain there when I click again after a successful update.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to fix things

via HTML

```
<a ... data-type="textarea" data-value="<html-text>">
```

or via Javascript

```
$().editable({"value":"<html-text>"})
```

Replace `<html-text>` with the html text either in your template or in your javascript, depending on what you need.